# A short fantasy tale where a warrior faces a wizard with a genuine lightning bolt

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short fantasy tale (in the early 80s) in a very thin and dusty book. I have put bits and pieces as I remember it. The actions transpired in an ancient place; an oval plateau encircled by a rampart. The expanse was sandy and very cold -It reminded me of Mai-Dun Castle-. A mortal warrior walked into it while fleeing from an enemy and found a cave where he took refuge, not realizing that his presence went noticed by disturbing the air with his snoring and awoke a Wizard in the darkness of the cave. The sorcerer, who bore a wooden staff, confronted him and pursued him out of the cave to a sandy area. The warrior used all the crafts he possessed, sword, ax, arrows, against his new foe without success. Then, the wizard started to attack him with lightnings bolts triggered from his staff. With no more weapons, the warrior was able to dodge the flash strikes with his shield. Here there is a gap. I don't remember what happened, but at the end, the warrior's foot struck against something, and he picked it up. It was a smooth and polished stick of pure porcelain six feet long.  It was a genuine thunderbolt made of sand fused by the sorcerer's lightning. When the wizard was ready to kill him, the warrior used the tube as a javelin piercing the Wizard, in his heart, who evaporated into the cold air.

I would really like to read again this weird fantasy tale where a wizard was defeated with his own lightning bolt.